# MS Access, Inventory Levels query taking too long. Alternatives?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that generates the daily changes of a number of SKU's. 
It also adds 0's because the report requires them.

This currently generates around 60,000 records of data like in this image:
[image: Inventory Report Table]

I then have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.Date, t1.[Part SKU], t1.[SKU Name], t1.[Inventory Change], (SELECT SUM(t2.[Inventory Change]) 
    FROM [Inventory Report Table] t2
    WHERE t1.[Date] >= t2.[Date]
    AND t1.[Part SKU] = [t2.Part SKU]) AS [Inventory Level]
FROM [Inventory Report Table] AS t1
ORDER BY t1.Date, t1.[Part SKU];
```

Basically what this query does is it sums all records based on Part SKU where Date >= Date for that SKU.

Giving a result like this:
[image]

The problem is, it takes too long.
I've been trying to find a workaround for this now...

But I'm stuck

Comment: *Takes too long* is very relative. Some feel 1 min is too long, some 30 secs. Please describe.

Comment: 60K records shouldn't take very long at all.  Either your pipe is too small or your tables aren't indexed properly.

Comment: Too long as in the "Running Query" indicator doesn't move a single pixel in 2 hours and the fan on my 8 core i7 16gb RAM computer is spinning like crazy.

It was ok with ~40K records, the query took about 20 minutes then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT t1.Date, t1.[Part SKU], t1.[SKU Name], t1.[Inventory Change],
       (SELECT SUM(t2.[Inventory Change]) 
        FROM [Inventory Report Table] t2
        WHERE t1.[Date] >= t2.[Date] AND t1.[Part SKU] = [t2.Part SKU]
       ) AS [Inventory Level]
FROM [Inventory Report Table] AS t1
ORDER BY t1.Date, t1.[Part SKU];
```

For performance, I would try the following two indexes:  `[Inventory Report Table](Date, [Part SKU])` and `[Inventory Report Table]([Part SKU], Date)`.  Yes, both are desirable, one for the subquery and one for the outer query.

This might help.  However, what you really need a cumulative sum function.  You might consider upgrading to a database such as SQL Server or Postgres that offers this functionality.

Comment: The query runs a LOT faster (like 10 times faster)... But the problem is, when I turn it in to a Make Table Query, it won't make the table... The "Run Query" indicator is stuck at 1 pixel... Even when the query itself takes about 3 minutes to run or to export as Excel...

Comment: Ok so what I left this query as a select query and then created another query to take the data from this query and turned that into a make table query.

This solves it... And with your index suggestion (I have no idea how to do it in SQL though) the query is also faster. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can it be:

```
SELECT t1.DATE
    ,t1.[Part SKU]
    ,t1.[SKU Name]
    ,t1.[Inventory Change]
    ,SUM(t2.[Inventory Change])  AS [Inventory Level]

FROM [Inventory Report Table] AS t1
left join [Inventory Report Table] t2
on t1.[Part SKU] = [t2.Part SKU]

WHERE t1.[Date] >= t2.[Date]

group by t1.DATE
    ,t1.[Part SKU]
    ,t1.[SKU Name]
    ,t1.[Inventory Change]

ORDER BY t1.DATE
    ,t1.[Part SKU];
```

**PS:** I haven't test the query it's just an idea.